# Error running composer

Tags: php, yii2, composer-php

When I run:

```
composer global required “fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.3.1”,
```

It's report an error like this:

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Composer\Package\RootPackage::getConfig()
```

Comment: copyedits and composer-php tag

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
sudo composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.3.1"
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not work, I found the reason that's my composer version is 1.0.2beta thus I used           sudo apt install composer so I could not fulfill the  composer self-update

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your composer version is latest; if not, upgrade your composer.

   > Note: If you are in Ubuntu, and you use sudo apt install composer, plz remove it, install use curl or widget install again.
2. If your composer version is already the latest, plz use sudo